# How can i parse this json output?

Tags: ios

```
["from": /topics/nursery-a, "is_background": false, "flag": 1, "data": {"msg_head_id":{"msg_head_id":7,"name":"Section","created_at":"2017-01-24 19:34:43"},"msg_title":"hello","message":{"msg_head_id":7,"doc_url":"","msg_title":"hello","created_at":"2017-02-24 10:11:07","message_id":225,"message":"welcome"},"user":{"user_id":57,"gcm_registration_id":"","name":"Iron","created_at":"2016-12-27 12:41:18","email":"info@mail.in"}}, "title": Smart , "collapse_key": do_not_collapse]
```

Comment: It's going to be very hard to parse this. This isn't valid JSON. You're missing some quotation marks and the top level `[` and `]` should be `{` and `}`. Paste this into http://jsonlint.com to see.

Comment: Use [`NSJSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization). Google "ios swift jsonserialization tutorial" or "ios objective-c nsjsonserialization tutorial".

Answer (score 0):

it's not a valid JSON. it should be start and close with { and }, remove [ and ], also quotation mark is missing. After these changes try this in http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 0):

According to the official site, json is built on two structures -- which named dictionary and array in iOS.

So this json output isn't valid json. The value of a json key should be one of array/object(key value pairs)/number/string/boolean/null.

The `from`, `title`, `collapse_key` should boxed in `""` to be a string.

And the json output should start and end with `{}` not `[]`.